# What are the limitations of localstorage keys?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

When I query localStorage.feature7f1c3c10-048d-4ced-8ab8-b88ac91b59ee in an inspector console I receive the below.

> SyntaxError: At least one digit must occur after a decimal point
>   line: 515
>   message: "At least one digit must occur after a decimal point"
>   stack: "eval@[native code]↵evaluate@[native code]↵_evaluateOn↵_evaluateAndWrap↵evaluate"

Simple question is why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The '-' is illegal in keys in dot notation. You will see that

```
localStorage['feature7f1c3c10-048d-4ced-8ab8-b88ac91b59ee']
```

is valid.

More on valid JS identifiers (that can be used as keys without quotes) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661197/valid-characters-for-javascript-variable-names).

Comment: or localStorage.getItem(key)

Comment: Is there any reason for me to pull out the '-' when I create these?  Best practice wise.

Comment: If you do not rely on using the dot notation, the dashes are just fine.